# Easily strip alpha channel from images in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the simplest way to strip the alpha channel (and possible convert images to greyscale) in Mathematica?

I would like to use `ImageAssemble`, but some of the images come with and some without an alpha channel.  Is there a simpler built-in way than manipulating the `ImageData` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RemoveAlphaChannel` function will do this.

Comment: @Mr. Yep. `New in 8`  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RemoveAlphaChannel.html

Answer (score 2):

For Mathematica 7, I believe this works:

```
ColorCombine@Most@ColorSeparate@# &
```

It's not robust at this point, but type checking could be added.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question (not sure it is) conversion to grayscale, is done with:

```
ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"]
```